# Cocurvature and the Gauss-Bonnet theorem

Tags: geometry

Is there similar equation as in the Gauss-Bonnet theorem with respect to cocurvature?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Might I suggest to provide more details of the question? As this is a site for references, and this seems not so like a complete reference... I am just suggesting, in any case.